# Airflow tasks are queued after added retry_exponential_backoff to true

Tags: airflow

#### Issue Summary

Few of my airflow tasks are still queued even after the next run is executed fine.

#### args

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'my-owner',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['email@org.com']
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_exponential_backoff': True,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 1)
}
```

Before implementing `retry_exponential_backoff` the dag was failed due to `Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table`.

After implementing `retry_exponential_backoff to True` there is no failure due to `Exceeded rate limits` but so far for one run I could see few tasks are still not yet triggered even after the next run executed.

[image]

What could be the issue? Appreciate your support.

Comment: The DAG is successfully executed after 3 hours. Not sure if this can be an issue or not. 
Any  inputs please ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can click on the queued (grey) task and select the first option: "Instance Details" Then on the first upper part you can read the section Task Instance Details which has details about the state of the task.

Now about your use case, we still need more details: airflow version, your schedule_interval, more logs, what Executors you are using, num_runs, concurrency, etc.
Please check the official Airflow Documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html)